# Compare grouped totals using two tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have two tables:

#### charges

```
id
booking_no
room_id
guest_id
product_id
unit_price
quantity
net_total
tax_total
gross_total
```

#### payments

```
id
booking_no
room_id
guest_id
payment_method
payment_amount
```

---

I want to get `sum(gross_total)` from the charges table and `sum(payment_amount)` from the payments table in a single query to compare the two totals.

`booking_no`, `room_id`, and `guest_id` are the key fields for these two tables.

There can be multiple rows in both tables and row counts can be different.

I can get totals separately from:

**charges**

```
SELECT SUM(gross_total) AS total_charges
FROM charges 
GROUP BY booking_no, room_id, guest_id
```

**payments**

```
SELECT SUM(payment_amount) AS total_payments
FROM payments
GROUP BY booking_no, room_id, guest_id
```

Is there anyway to get something like this, using a single query?

```
SELECT SUM(gross_total) AS total_charges, SUM(payment_amount) AS total_payments 
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume there are no payments without a charge:

```
SELECT SUM(gross_total) AS charge_total
     , ( SELECT SUM(payment_amount)
         FROM payments p
         WHERE p.booking_no = c.booking_no 
           AND p.room_id = c.room_id
           AND p.guest_id = c.guest_id ) AS total_payments  
FROM charges c
GROUP BY booking_no, room_id, guest_id
```

Whilst this is a valid query, I suspect that you would like to know which guest, etc that are involved for each row in the result

```
SELECT booking_no, room_id, guest_id
     , SUM(gross_total) AS charge_total
     , ( SELECT SUM(payment_amount)
         FROM payments p
         WHERE p.booking_no = c.booking_no 
           AND p.room_id = c.room_id
           AND p.guest_id = c.guest_id ) AS total_payments  
FROM charges c
GROUP BY booking_no, room_id, guest_id
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative:

```
SELECT
  charges_grouped.booking_no
  , charges_grouped.room_id
  , charges_grouped.guest_id
  , charges_grouped.charge_total
  , payments_grouped.payment_total
  , COALESCE(payments_grouped.total_payments, 0) AS total_payments_no_null
FROM (
  SELECT
    booking_no
    , room_id
    , guest_id
    , SUM(c.gross_total) AS charge_total    
  FROM charges c
  GROUP BY booking_no, room_id, guest_id
) AS charges_grouped
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    booking_no
    , room_id
    , guest_id
    , SUM(payment_amount) AS payment_total
  FROM payments
  GROUP BY booking_no, room_id, guest_id
) AS payments_grouped
  ON charges_grouped.booking_no = payments_grouped.booking_no 
  AND charges_grouped.room_id = payments_grouped.room_id
  AND charges_grouped.guest_id = payments_grouped.guest_id
-- GROUP BY charges_grouped.booking_no, charges_grouped.room_id, charges_grouped.guest_id
;
```

I might (¿Should at least in theory?) perform better than the @Lennart's solution using a dependent subquery.

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b6978/5).

**N.B.**:

- As @Lennart pointed out: The last `GROUP BY` (now changed to a comment) is not necessary with the sub-selects taking care of the aggregation. (Originally, I aggregated over the joined actual tables - which led to wrong results for identical **booking_no**, **room_id** and **guest_id** combinations with more than one record in at least one of the tables.
- As @Lennart suggests: If you don't need/want **NULL** for 'no payment' yet (which means, you would no longer be able to tell them apart from transfers and, e.g., refunds amounting to zero), use `COALESCE`.
- If you care only for charges, for which payments have been recorded, replace `LEFT JOIN` by `INNER JOIN`.

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.